# I would like to contribute my time for free to a Ruby open source project, what are some beginner friendly Ruby projects?

Tags: open-source, ruby, free-time

I think I am at a point where I can truly contribute to a Ruby open source project, can you suggest one or more that would be open to having a true beginner contribute. This would be my first group project where I would like to be 'mentored' or something similar by a more experienced coder. I would be able to work in my free-time and for free.

Comment: Maybe "Hello World"?

Comment: I made it past hello world months ago, its only one line in Ruby

Comment: Try #ruby at Freenode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head over to [OpenHatch](http://openhatch.org/) or [ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/) and do some looking around.  Both of these sites are good places to start looking for open source projects to contribute to.